# Something wrong with deinstallation of GIT in Windows

Tags: git, git-svn

I tried to remove GIT on my windows-XP, by means of the Windows/Configuration/Software menu. After some error message (which I cannot remember), it removed all files. I checked it, and there are no files with ptp in the name left on the entire system.

A problem remained however: each time I opened windows-explorer, a nasty error message came calling for a dll file that wasn't there anymore.

Anyone know what is going on here? A wild guess: could there be any interference between svn and git, if certain files are linked to both git and svn?

Personally, I went to the registry. I found that many traces to GIT are left in the registry after deinstalling GIT the "windows-way". I removed each one carefully by hand, which seems to have solved my problem. This is of course a dangerous path, but I had no choice. Perhaps it is a good idea to look into the Windows-deinstallation script very carefully.

Comment: This seems a more appropriate question for serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove an explorer extension (not sure if that is the terminology, it is however the concept).

I believe you can use [Microsoft's 'autoruns'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to do it.